# Not able to align menu items horizontally in navigation bar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, navbar

I am developing a react app using create-react-app. In the beginning, I am not able to align the menu items in my navbar horizontaly. Refer Screenshot below.

[image]

Also, I can not figure out why my navbar doesn't picking up the css, as you can see I have specifically mentioned the inverse theme of the navbar. Here is my NavigationBar.js file

```js
import React from "react";
import {Navbar, Nav, NavItem} from "react-bootstrap";

class Header extends React.Component{
    render() {
        return (
            <Navbar inverse>
                <Navbar.Header>
                    <Navbar.Brand>
                        <a href="#brand">Tweelyze</a>
                    </Navbar.Brand>
                </Navbar.Header>
                <Nav>
                    <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#">Link1</NavItem>
                    <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#">Link2</NavItem>
                    <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#">Link2</NavItem>
                    <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#">Link2</NavItem>
                    <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#">Link2</NavItem>
                </Nav>
            </Navbar>
        );
    }
}

export default Header;
```

I want my navbar to be something like this

[image]

Here is my App.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Header from "./NavigationBar"
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div><Header/></div>

    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

And Index.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/App';
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

What exactly is that I am missing?

Comment: Please refer to this: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: You need to import a stylesheet as react-bootstrap doesn't come with styling per default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your bootstrap styles are being imported correctly.

Add this to your index.html (not index.js)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

you can also remove the import for it in index.js. Alternatively you can probably import it in index.js by using

import 'bootstrap';